# Xamarin Forms: Why FormsApplicationActivity extends from Activity instead of FragmentActivity?

Tags: xamarin, android-viewpager

Because of that, I can’t use ViewPager with Xamarin Forms.

In the custom android renderer I need to get a reference from FragmentActivity to set the Fragment Adapter. But I can’t do it because the parent is an Activity.

So, CarouselPage does not fit the most basics requirements for a gallery/pager, but also it is imposible to use a ViewPager as a custom renderer control.

Is that right? Am I unable to implement the funcionality of a View Pager with Xamarin Forms?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ViewPager element in a Xamarin.Forms project, you just cannot use the Fragment variation.

The steps I took to create the ViewPager:

1. Create a custom renderer:

   ```
   public class TutorialPageViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<TutorialPageView, ViewPager> { ... }
   ```
2. Create an Adapter that can be used by the ViewPager. This adapter however is not the FragmentPagerAdapter, but the more generic PagerAdapter. An example can be found here: http://techglimpse.com/create-horizontal-swipe-gesture-android-viewpager-pageradapter/
3. Since I used Xamarin.Forms (XF) views as content for the ViewPager, I had to use the RenderFactory to get the native view from the XF view. Then get the ViewGroup item from the returned VisualElement, add that to the ViewGroup that is given and return the view.

   ```
   public override Java.Lang.Object InstantiateItem ( ViewGroup container, int position )
   {
       var view = _contentViews [ position ];
       view.Layout ( _bounds ); // Rectangle
       var viewRenderer = RendererFactory.GetRenderer ( view );
       var nativeView = viewRenderer.ViewGroup;
       container.AddView ( nativeView, position );
       return nativeView;
   }
   ```

As you can see I also had to set the bounds on the XF View (`view`). Without this, the view had no proper bounds and did not display. These bounds were set from the `TutorialPageViewRenderer` in the `OnAttachedToWindow` method.

If more information is required, please let me know. At the moment I'm not able to put the code on-line in its entirety.

Comment: Could you provide me with more details on how you achieved this? I have been trying to implement the same, but the view pager does not seem to get shown